# "Ничего удивительного нет в том, чтобы..." - здесь придаточное изъяснительное?

Tags: синтаксис

> Ничего удивительного нет в том, **чтобы попросить гостей снять обувь в
>   холле**.

Скажите, пожалуйста, выделенный фрагмент это изъяснительное предложение?

Plus, к сожалению я не понимаю, почему глагол "попросить" стоит в инфинитиве... Кто просит гостей снять обувь? Это неличное предложение?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Здесь придаточное изъяснительное.

""Союз чтобы всегда имеет целевое значение, и он может использоваться в придаточном цели.

*Надо было прожить великую жизнь [зачем? с какой целью?], чтобы негры просили заступничества у русского графа (Песков).*

В придаточном **изъяснительном** также может использоваться этот союз, но вопрос от главного предложения к придаточному будет иным (вопросы косвенных падежей), а придаточные будут иметь значение желательности, возможности, необходимости.

Ср.: *Елизавета Киевна просила [о чём?], чтобы ей самой разрешили отвезти его в большой лазарет (А.Н. Толстой).*"

См: [Придаточные дополнительные (изъяснительные)](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_dopolnitelnye_izyasnitelnye.html)

(2) Сказуемое в безличном предложении может быть выражено инфинитивом.

Answer (score 3):

Это **приместоименное изъяснительное придаточное** с обязательным коррелятом В ТОМ (другое название этого типа предложений - вмещающие СПП). Придаточное раскрывает содержание коррелята, при этом обычно используются два союза: ЧТО и ЧТОБЫ.

Сравнить:

(1) Ничего удивительного нет в том, что он попросил гостей снять обувь в холле.

(2) Ничего удивительного нет в том, чтобы попросить гостей снять обувь в холле.

Союз ЧТОБЫ относится к ирреальной модальности (возможное действие), в отличие от союза ЧТО.